# ¿Cómo guardar imagen en mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-mvc, spring-boot, blob

Pretendo, mediante un formulario html con un input type file, enviar el archivo al servidor y grabarlo en la base de datos. No tengo muy claro qué tipo de dato envía el formulario al servidor para recogerlo en una propiedad de clase.

Comment: podrías agregar la porción de código donde has intentado guardar la imagen?

Comment: se puede almacenar la imagen en BD, pero generalmente lo que se hace es subir la imagen a tu servidor y luego en la BD se almacena solo la ruta de la imagen hosteada en el server.

Comment: Lo que pretendo no es insertar en BD un String con la ruta del archivo sino grabar el archivo en la BD en un campo tipo Blob.

Comment: @Hector claramente en el título dice MYSQL

Answer (score 6):

Puedes grabar facil y prácticamente una imagen (u otro formato de archivo) en `MySQL` como un dato `BLOB`.

Los datos `BLOB` son datos almacenados en cadenas de bytes y permite poder guardar archivos de múltiples formatos.

Para que tengas una idea hay varios tipos de datos `BLOB` en `MySQL` en base al tamaño máximo que pueden almacenar:

> **BLOB** = (65,535 bytes, 65KB)
>   **MEDIUMBLOB** =  (16,777,215 bytes, 16MB)
>   **LONGBLOB** =  (4,294,967,295 bytes, 4GB)

Te debo el código para poder convertir una imagen en bytes para luego subirlo a `MySQL` con Spring Framework ya que tengo ese código pero en VB.NET.

Al igual que para mostrarlo en la página se debe utilizar otro código para descifrar esa cadena de bytes.

Entiendo que mi respuesta no es del todo directa y es abstracta pero, si alguien tiene el código que edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Hola, tendras el codigo para vb.net, estoy buscando como guardar una imagen..

Answer (score 2):

Lo más eficiente es que no guardes la imagen como tal, sino el enlace a ella. Así puedes crear un campo de tipo VARCHAR que se llame "link" y en el almacenar la ruta hasta la imagen, por ejemplo "/img/imagen1.jpg" La ruta sería la relativa al script donde se carga la imagen.

Como resultado de la query tendrás que poner el resultado del campo en el tag  Asi en PHP sería algo como

```
$sql = "select link from tabla";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<img src='".$row["link"]."' >";
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

saludos

Comment: Hola José tu respuesta está basada en php, en cambio la pregunta esta etiquetada como __spring-mvc__ lo cual es java, saludos.

Comment: pero el OP está solicitando como hacerlo en spring y en base de datos.

Comment: Es cierto, no me había dado cuenta. Es la primera vez que accedo al entorno. Gracias también por la edición del código

Answer (score 0):

Para permitir la subida de archivos con Spring MVC debes configurar un `MultipartResolver`, este te permitirá obtener los archivos subidos mediante un objeto `MultipartFile`, el mismo contiene el conjunto de bytes que conforma el archivo, independientemente de cuál se su tipo, lo siguiente que debes hacer es guardar esto bytes en la base de datos, para ello utilizarías el tipo `BLOB` que permite almacenar este tipo de información.

Si tienes la siguiente tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE imagen(nombre VARCHAR(100), tipo VARCHAR(10), tamano BIGINT, pixel BLOB(10M))
```

El controlador Spring MVC sería:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(
        @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {

    if (!file.isEmpty()) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO imagen (nombre, tipo, tamano, pixel) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";

        String nombre = file.getOriginalFilename();
        String tipo   = file.getContentType();
        Long tamano   = file.getSize();
        byte[] pixel  = file.getBytes();

        jdbc.update(sql, nombre, tipo, tamano, pixel);
    }

    return "redirect:/";
}
```

Usamos el método `file.getBytes()` para obtener los bytes del archivo y luego lanzar la consulta para guardarlos.

Puedes ver este tutorial: http://acodigo.blogspot.com/2017/07/subir-archivos-al-servidor.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  public bool grabaimagen(string codigo, PictureBox pb)
    {
        conecta2();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("update miembros set foto = @foto where codigo ='"+ codigo + "'",cn2);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@foto", MySqlDbType.LongBlob);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pb.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        cmd.Parameters["@foto"].Value = ms.GetBuffer();
        int resultado = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn2.Close();

        if (resultado > 0) { return true; } else { return false; }
    }

    public void verimagen(PictureBox pb, string codigo)
    {
        try
        {
            conecta2();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select foto from miembros where codigo = '" + vcodigo + "'", cn2);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "img");
            byte[] datos = new byte[0];
            DataRow dr = ds.Tables["img"].Rows[0];
            datos = (byte[])dr["foto"];
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(datos);
            pb.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {


        }

        cn2.Close();
    }
```

//para insertar solo cambia el update por insert into tabla values (campo, campo)
//espero te funcione

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu respuesta de mejor manera. También puedes revisar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException, SQLException {
    Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/databaseName", "usuario", "password");
    String sqlQuery = "insert into tu_tabla(campo_foto) values ( ?)";

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
      conn.setAutoCommit(false);
      File archivo = new File("myPhoto.png");
      fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);
      ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
      ps.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());
      ps.executeUpdate();
      conn.commit();
    } finally {
      ps.close();
      fis.close();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hola user12717. Por favor brinda más detales sobre por qué este código va a resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola, yo coloqué la respuesta que está debajo sobre insertar un BLOB en la base. Si quieres podrías ayudar editando mi respuesta y colocando el código en framework Java para hacerlo!

Comment: @AgustinM. esta no es una respuesta válida y no solo porque no explica nada sino porque asume que el archivo se está obteniendo de disco en lugar de obtenerlo desde la información del formulario html.

Comment: Entiendo Luiggi. Yo solo comentaba que si tenía el código correcto podía aportarlo a mi respuesta. Desconozco sobre este framework y como hacerlo yo precisamente.